# $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\, dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms

I am trying to proof:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\left(\ln\left(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)dx \hskip50pt (1)$$

where $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m$ positive.

I got inspiration in this post: [Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{f(\frac{k}{n}) }$ $=\int_0^1 f(x)dx.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692088/prove-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n-sum-k-1nf-frackn) and the answer [Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{f(\frac{k}{n}) }$ $=\int_0^1 f(x)dx.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692088/prove-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n-sum-k-1nf-frackn/787122#787122) but I am not sure about how to deal with the $\frac{m}{n}$ term since my partition $\{0 +\frac{m}{n},\frac{1}{n}+\frac{m}{n},\frac{2}{n}+\frac{m}{n},\dots,\frac{(n-1)}{n},1+\frac{m}{n}\}$ isn`t from $0$ to $1$.

Maybe (1) is false? Am I missing something?

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\ln x$ is strictly increasing, then
$$
\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)<\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}\ln x\,dx
<\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)
<
\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)-\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}\ln x\,dx
<
\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$
But
$$
\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
=\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{k}\right)< \frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{m}{k}\right)<\frac{m}{kn},
$$
while
$$
\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{k+1}\right)=
\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{m-1}{k+1}\right)
$$
If $m\ge 1$, then $\ln\left(1+\frac{m-1}{k+1}\right)\ge 0$. If $m\in(0,1)$, then
$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{m-1}{k+1}\right)=\frac{1}{k+1}\ln\left(1+\frac{m-1}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}\ge \frac{1}{k+1}\ln\left(1+(k+1)\frac{m-1}{k+1}\right)=\frac{\ln m}{k+1}.
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{1}{(k+1)n}\min\{0,\ln m\}<\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)-\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}\ln x\,dx<\frac{m}{kn}
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{\min\{0,\ln m\}}{n}(\ln(n+1)-\ln 2) <
\frac{\min\{0,\ln m\}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(k+1)}<\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\right)
-\int_{1/n}^1\ln x\,dx<\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{m}{kn}
=\frac{m}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}
<\frac{m}{n}(1+\ln n)
$$
since $1+\ln n>\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I don't see why is this inequality true:
$$0<\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\right)-\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}\ln x\,dx$$.

Comment: @mathstudent007 See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you, it is very clarifying.